# Why does Spring obviously merges two different beans?

Tags: java, spring

I am quite new to Spring and atm checking out XML-driven Spring.

Now my problem is that Spring somehow merges two different bean-objects coming from the same bean-class. It treats them as one single object.

Please, take a look at the following code:

```
<bean id="shapeList1" class="coreservlets.ShapeListMaker" >
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list>
        <ref local="shape1" /> 
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="shapeList2" class="coreservlets.ShapeListMaker"  >
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref local="shape2" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

...the related class:

```
public class ShapeListMaker {

public ShapeListMaker (List<Shape> shapes) {
    shapelist = shapes;
}

public ShapeListMaker (Shape shape) {
    shapelist.add(shape);
}

private static List<Shape> shapelist = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comparing both objects (shapeList1 == shapeList2) returns **true**. Printing out one of the lists produces both shapes, **shape1** and **shape2**... Why? I am confused...

Via the same xml-file I created some other bean objects in the same way (the **shape** beans) without any trouble or merging.

Comment: Show us more of your code. How are you getting `shapeList1` and `shapeList2` in your code? Post a complete, but small program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction!
What do you mean by "how are you getting..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shapeList is static ;) so the reference is shared and will be the same on both classes.

Comment: That was it! Thanks :)

(To myself: Lession to be learned: 'Purpose and effect of the 'Static' attribute')